# Sending Variable from php inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have web ecommerce, and it use an API from delivery agent website rajaongkir.com,
I want to use the price of delivery agent to be a variable in my database.

Her is file order.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<form action="input.php?input=inputform" method="post">
<table class="zebra-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Kurir</th>
                <th>Servis</th>
                <th>Deskripsi Servis</th>
                <th>Lama Kirim (hari)</th>
                <th>Total Biaya (Rp)</th>
                <th>Opsi</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="resultsbox"></tbody>
</table>
```

script.js

```
function cekHarga(){
//var origin = $('#oricity').val();
var origin = 35;
var destination = $('#descity').val();
var weight = $('#berat').val();
var courier = $('#service').val();
$.ajax({
    url:'process.php?act=cost',
    data:{origin:origin,destination:destination,weight:weight,courier:courier},
    success:function(response){
        $('#resultsbox').html(response);
    },
    error:function(){
        $('#resultsbox').html('ERROR');
    }
});
```

}

process.php

```
if(isset($_GET['act'])):
switch ($_GET['act']) {
$cost = $IdmoreRO->hitungOngkir($origin,$destination,$weight,$courier);
    //parse json
    $costarray = json_decode($cost);
    $results = $costarray->rajaongkir->results;
    if(!empty($results)):
        foreach($results as $r):
            foreach($r->costs as $rc):
                foreach($rc->cost as $rcc):
                echo "<tr><td>$r->code</td><td>$rc->service</td><td>$rc->description</td><td>$rcc->etd</td><td>".number_format($rcc->value)."</td> <td></td></tr>";
                    $bayarr=$rcc->value;                                                 
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
endif;
```

I can access variable $bayarr at form in order.php.

How can I send variable $bayarr at process.php to order.php ?

[image: <tbody id="resultsbox"></tbody>]

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. If you want to "send" the variable to `order.php` maybe a header redirect (`header("Location: order.php");`) is what you are looking for. If you want to use functions from order.php, you could use a class approach (defining, including and initiating, that is). Please be more precise on what you actually want.

Comment: when I try all code paste here, it say error to post. I'm too noob at php programming. I will learn more. thx for advice

Answer (score 0):

use `json` to send more than 1 value from ajax call.

```
$arr['html'] = "<tr><td>$r->code</td><td>$rc->service</td><td>$rc->description</td><td>$rcc->etd</td><td>".number_format($rcc->value)."</td> <td></td></tr>";
$arr['price'] = $bayarr=$rcc->value;
echo json_encode($arr);
```

In ajax success,

```
success: function(response){
      var content = JSON.parse(response);
      $('#resultsbox').html(response.html);
      alert(response.price);// will have your price here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get some specific value with the same request which gives you HTML you can add the param inside some of the HTML tags at your response and after that to parse it..

Something as:

```
foreach($rc->cost as $rcc):
    echo "<tr data-bayarr=\"{$rcc->value}\"><td>$r->code</td><td>$rc->service</td><td>$rc->description</td><td>$rcc->etd</td><td>".number_format($rcc->value)."</td> <td></td></tr>";
endforeach;
```

After that just proceed it at your ajax succes as:

```
success:function(response){
    $('#resultsbox').html(response);
    /* Because its in a foreach there will be multiple bayarrs .. */
    $('#resultsbox').find('[data-bayarr]').each(function( i ) {
        alert($(this).data('bayarr'));
    });
},
```

The other way is to convert the response into json array where you have both HTML and bayarr values..

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your entire `$results` array, which you're looping, if you had to:

```
<input type="hidden" id="data_clustor" name="data_clustor"
value="<?php echo base64_encode(json_encode($results)); ?>">
```

Then just reference `$('#data_clustor').val();` and pass it to your next PHP page where you'd simply do:

```
$results=json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['data_clustor']));
```

and loop it all over again. Or pass along only the data you're interested in rather than the whole entire massive array.

Without seeing your code which calls `cekHarga()` or the elements you're referencing with:

```
var destination = $('#descity').val();
var weight = $('#berat').val();
var courier = $('#service').val();
```

It becomes a bit difficult to see what you're trying to do, since it's unclear where you're pulling these fields with these ids from if none of the code you've showed us contains it.

Alternatively, just use PHP sessions, and keep the information loaded on the server for the specific user in `$_SESSION`. Write to it whatever you want to remember, then read from it when you need it on the other page.